# Why value returned from JSON is not comparable to NSNull?

Tags: json, swift, binary-operators

I am returning String values from API via Swift 4 JSON Codable method.

I know few values are "null" or nil, so to avoid crashes I am trying to implement code. Here is the code giving the subject error (on NSNull comparison):

```
if Cur[indexPath.row].cap == nil || Cur[indexPath.row].cap == NSNull {
    print("Could not find the value")
    CapVal = "N/A"
} else {
    CapVal = Cur[indexPath.row].cap!
}
```

The error:

**Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'NSNull.Type**

I tried to cast it as String too: `Cur[indexPath.row].cap as? String` still got the same error.

Comment: Why would you want to compare a Swift optional to `NSNull`?

Comment: I want to assign value to variable when value is returning null. So, instead of crashing I get "N/A" String.

Comment: An optional can't return `NSNull`... If it has no value, it will return `nil`.

Comment: So why I am getting crashes when there is null value for a key in JSON?

Comment: First of all, learn how to handle optionals. Checking for `nil` and using force unwrapping otherwise is not the way to go. Moreover, include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: I used guard let syntax. I was handling the nil perfectly. But App crashed when value was null. So I asked the question here.

Comment: `NSNull` is a class. Even if the compiler allowed it, the check would always fail. But it's a singleton, so `NSNull()` will get you the shared instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `JSONDecoder`, both missing values and values that are explicitly designated as `null` will be returned as `nil`:

Consider this JSON:

```
{"foo": "a", "bar": null}
```

And this `struct`:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    var foo: String
    var bar: String?
    var baz: String?
}
```

If you use `JSONDecoder`, you can just do:

```
guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data) else { ... }

let bar = result.bar ?? "N/A"
```

---

I know you were asking about `Codable` in Swift 4, but just for your reference, if you were using `JSONSerialization`, though, you could theoretically test for `null`, because `JSONSerialization` *does* return `null` values as `NSNull`:

```
guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else { ... }

let bar = json["bar"]

if bar == nil || bar is NSNull {
    // bar was either not found or `null`
} else {
    // bar was found and was not `null` 
}
```

Personally, though, I'd just optionally cast to string and use `nil` coalescing operator if the cast failed, e.g.

```
let bar = (json["bar"] as? String) ?? "N/A"
```

But, this is all moot with Swift 4's `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the help. I implemented - let bar = result.bar ?? "N/A" - in the code and works great. Appreciated!